# Angular Material Tabs - Full Height of Component not being applied

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to get my tab to become the full height of the underlying content but cannot figure out how to do it.

I've tried setting height: 100% and similar things that I have found but nothing seems to work.

HTML

```
<mat-tab-group [selectedIndex]="0"  dynamicHeight>
    <mat-tab label="Summary">
            <p>Hello Summary</p>
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Vehicles">
        <mat-tab-group [selectedIndex]="0"  dynamicHeight>
            <mat-tab label="Cars">
                <app-cars-component></app-cars-component>
            </mat-tab>
            <mat-tab label="Trucks">
                <app-trucks-component></app-cars-component>
            </mat-tab>
            <mat-tab label="Planes">
                <app-planes-component></app-cars-component>
            </mat-tab>
        </mat-tab-group>
    </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Each component within the tabs will range in size from 100px in height to 1500px (which requires scrolling) depending on the content in it at the time.

However the tabs never take on the 100% of the height of the component.

Comment: have to tried with `ViewEncapsulation.None` and adding CSS in that component

Comment: @KiranMistry can you elaborate on the solution?

Comment: Are you trying to ensure the mat-tab-group takes the full height of its parent or are you trying to make sure each mat-tab child displays fully without scrolling?

Comment: @robbieAreBest i want the mat-tab to fully display the contents of the nested component without scrolling

Answer (score -2):

With `Angular Material` you will need to penetrate the styles encapsulation rules. Until this moment there is one main solution for this, which is to force your custom styles to override the default ones. To do so, you will need to add a deprecated rule named `::ng-deep` followed by the name of the class you want to override its styles. The name of the class should be retrived from the DOM directly.

In the stylesheet of your component or in your global stylesheet you can then do the following:

```
::ng-deep .mat-tab-label .mat-tab-label-content {
   //styles go here
}
```

Comment: From Angular docos: https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep that is a big no go as it is deprecated and you just don't what updates to browsers/platforms/libraries can cause/result in

Comment: not only that your solution is inappropriate, but you also did not include WHAT styles should be included...